# Let $f(x) = \int^x_1 \frac{\ln t}{1+t}dt; $ for $x >0$ then find the value of ....

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

- Problem :

> Define $f(x) = \int^x_1 \frac{\ln t}{1+t}dt$ for $x >0$ then find the value of $f(e) +f(\frac{1}{e}).$

- My approach :

$f(x) = \int^x_1 \frac{\ln t}{1+t}dt;  $
$f'(x) = \frac{\ln x}{1+x}$ Using Lebnitz's rule

Will this approach is correct, please guide on this to find the value as required, will be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't look integrateable with elementary functions.

Comment: But there is no need to integrate. Only the specific value $f(e)+f(e^{-1})$ is asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**. Try the change of variable $t=\frac1u$ in the integrand,
$$
\int^x_1 \frac{\ln t}{1+t}dt=\int^{1/x}_1 \frac{-\ln u}{1+1/u}\frac{-du}{u^2}=\int^{1/x}_1 \frac{\ln u}{(1+u)u}\:du
$$ then finish with a partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: How should I go about the integration by parts?  It isn't clear to me.

Comment: @SimpleArt I meant a partial decomposition ;) Thanks.

Comment: Hm, so this comes out with logarithmic integrals?  Probably should've realized from the beginning.

Comment: @SimpleArt The OP is just asked to obtain $f(e)+f(1/e)$, isn't it?

Comment: For reference (to double check). If I am not mistaken, the end answer is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @OlivierOloa Yeah, I do think so.

Answer (score 6):

By setting $t=e^u$ we have
$$ f(x) = \int_{1}^{x}\frac{\log t}{1+t}\,dt = \int_{0}^{\log x}\frac{u e^u}{1+e^u}\,du $$
hence:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} f(e)+f(e^{-1}) &=& \int_{0}^{1}\frac{ue^u}{1+e^u}\,du-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(-u)e^{-u}}{1+e^{-u}}\,du\\ &=&\int_{0}^{1}u\cdot\frac{e^u+1}{e^u+1}\,du = \color{blue}{\frac{1}{2}}. \end{eqnarray*}$$